# How to get uncommon elements from ArrayList based on order

Tags: java

I am comparing two ArrayLists based on the Order

The size of total_list will be always bigger than the sub_list

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONException;

public class MrTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JSONException
    {



        ArrayList<String> total_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> sub_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> un_common_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        total_list.add("Beverages");
        total_list.add("Hot");
        total_list.add("Sai1");
        total_list.add("Sai2");
        total_list.add("Sai3");


        sub_list.add("Sai1");
        sub_list.add("Sai2");
        sub_list.add("Sai3");




        for(int i=0;i<total_list.size();i++)
        {

            String total_name = total_list.get(i);
            String sub_name = sub_list.get(i);

            if(total_name.equals(sub_name))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                un_common_list.add(total_name);
            }


        }


        System.out.println(un_common_list);
    }
}
```

I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at MrTest.main(MrTest.java:35)
```

where as i am expecting the output as

```
[Beverages, Hot]
```

Could anybody pleasse help me , as how to get Output as

```
[Beverages, Hot] in this case ??
```

Comment: The array lists are of different sizes, you cannot use `i` for both.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<total_list.size();i++)
        {

            String total_name = total_list.get(i);
            String sub_name = sub_list.get(i);
}

if total list size is 200, and sublist smaller, of course you'll get that error

Comment: @BartHofma yes i understood that , how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want:

```
total_list.removeAll(sub_list);
```

If you want to preserve `total_list`:

```
List<String> uncommon = new ArrayList<>(total_list);
uncommon.removeAll(sub_list);
```

Comment: No , i want to get the un common elements based on the Order of Insertion only .

Comment: this changed total_list too.

Comment: @kent yes, see edit. Preethi, what do you mean "based on insertion order"? This code produces the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same index for both lists, causing the sublist to go out of bounds. Use a loop within a loop, and use a boolean to check if it matches any of the values, if it didnt match, then it should add the string to the uncommon list.

```
boolean inlist=false;
 for(int i=0;i<total_list.size();i++)
    {

        String total_name = total_list.get(i);

        for(int k=0;k<sub_list.size();k++)
        {
            String sub_name = sub_list.get(k);


            if(total_name.equals(sub_name))
            {
              inlist=true;
            }

        }
       if (!inlist){un_common_list.add(total_name);}
       inlist=false;
  }
```

Comment: The output i am getting is [Beverages, Beverages, Beverages, Hot, Hot, Hot, Sai1, Sai1, Sai2, Sai2, Sai3, Sai3]

Comment: Where as i am expecting output as  [Beverages, Hot]

Comment: yes its working , its a great help , thank you very very much .

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<total_list.size();i++) 
    // Total_list size is 5
    {

        String total_name = total_list.get(i);
        String sub_name = sub_list.get(i);
        // sub_list size is 3, 
        // but you are calling sublist.get(3), sublist.get(4) and sublist.get(5)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would go with 1 loop, first make a copy of total_list using System.arraycopy to un_common_list, then iterate the sub_list and remove elements present in sub_list from the un_common_list, order should be preserved

however the removeAll() should preserve order too, just use the array copy thing

Answer (score 0):

if order of insertion is to be maintained then can try this condition

```
for(int i=0;i<total_list.size() && i<sub_list.size();i++)
```

Comment: Thank you , I see the output is [Beverages, Hot, Sai1] , i don't know why Sai1 is getting printed in the output .

Comment: now below to that use this un_common_list.removeAll(sub_list);....outside of both for loop